# Equality of two 8 bit buses in 7400 series logic?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, ttl

Is there a simple way to determine whether two 8-bit buses contain the same value?

I'm currently XORing each bit between the buses then feeding those results into a three-level tree of OR gates.  (The top of the tree being a NOR, rather than an OR.)

This is 8x XOR + 6x OR + 1x NOR gates, which is 4x 7400 series chips.

Comment: Use gates with wider inputs.

Comment: [74LS85](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/sn74ls85-446213.pdf) Qty 2

Comment: @EugeneSh. ... No, tie the "=" output of one to the "=" input of the next. Use the second "=" output. (I like dim's answer better)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Regarding your first suggestion of "wider inputs" unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a widely available 8-input NOR in the 74 series. Wikipedia mentions a 74HC4078 but it seems to have been discontinued..

Comment: @PeterGreen If we are speaking of a gate-level solution with two input gates, there is a mathematical lower bound on the number of gates to combine 16 inputs into 1 output, and it is `16-1 = 15`.

Comment: @chrisdew I had a quick look at your recent questions (one of [which](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237390/using-an-array-of-resistors-to-give-priority-on-a-bus) I also answered, by the way), and whatever you're building right now, I think you definitely should have a look at CPLDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 74HC688.

If you need something else, be sure to check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits.

Note that this 688 can still be sourced easily but most big 74xx building blocks are becoming less and less available. If you have a complex circuit to design, it may be time to learn CPLDs.

Comment: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MM/MM74HC688.pdf

Comment: I happen to know a Company/Freelancer who may or may not go by the name Asmyldof on the internet with a huge collection of DIP 74's, genuine NOS 90's, 80's, 70's and possibly 60's parts. Keep it a secret though, or he'll have ladies calling all day and all night. ;-)

Comment: @Asmyldof Oh so there actually is a way to [get some girls](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/240630/how-to-get-girls-with-electronic#comment525024_240630) with electronics? Nice to know! I'm starting to collect stuff at once.

Comment: Well, despite three people fave-ing [this chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30043248#30043248) it has not had the desired result :'(

Answer (score 0):

the 74HC85 is a 4-bit comparator, and 74HC688 is 8-bit.

Comment: Note that you can chain two or more 74(HC)85s together to compare more than four bits, at the expense of increased propagation delays.